# Trying to join output from ps and pwdx linux commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ps

I am trying to join output from ps and pwdx command. Can anyone point out the mistake in my command.

```
ps -eo %p,%c,%u,%a --no-headers | awk -F',' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf $i", 
"} ; printf pwdx $1; printf "\n" }'
```

I expect the last column in each row to be the process directory. But it just shows the value of $1 instead of the command output pwdx $1

This is my output sample (1 row):

```
163957, processA , userA , /bin/processA -args, 163957
```

I expected

```
163957, processA , userA , /bin/processA -args, /app/processA
```

Can anyone point out what I may be missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ps -eo %p,%c,%u,%a --no-headers | awk -F',' '{ printf "%s,", $0; "pwdx " $1 | getline; print gensub("^[0-9]*: *","","1",$0);}'
```

Explanation:

`awk '{print pwdx $1}'` will concatenate the awk variable `pwdx` (which is empty) and `$1` (pid). So, effectively, you were getting only the `pid` at the output.

In order to run a command and gets its output, you need to use this `awk` construct:

```
awk '{"some command" | getline; do_something_with $0}'
# After getline, the output will be present in $0.

#For multiline output, use this:
awk '{while ("some command" | getline){do_something_with $0}}'
# Each individual line will be present in subsequent run of the while loop.
```

Comment: To me, it does answer the OP question. @fpmurphy1 has explained the problem under 'explanation' in his answer. `awk '{print pwdx $1}' will concatenate the awk variable pwdx (which is empty) and $1 (pid). So, effectively, you were getting only the pid at the output.`

Comment: @fpmurphy1, the answer gives correct/fixed code; it also tells OP what was the mistake in their code. Which question in OP's post is unanswered? :-D Also note that I have not edited the answer after your comment ;-)

Comment: Thanks anishsane and fpmurphy ! This answer gives me the explanation i was looking for. Thanks for providing the solution and the explanation. This was absolutely correct

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying your example to focus on how to execute the `pwdx` command within `awk` and capture the result of this command into an `awk` variable as this is where you were having issues:

```
ps -eo %p,%c,%u,%a --no-headers | awk -F',' '{ system("pwdx "$1) | getline vpwdx; printf vpwdx $1}'
```

produces:

```
  15651665: /
  16651690: /
  16901691: /home/fpm
 169134248: /home/fpm
3424834254: /home/fpm/tmp
3425440181: /home/fpm/UDK2015
...
```

Comment: I think `printf vpwdx $1` is by mistake. it should be `printf vpwdx`. Besides, OP wanted to paste `ps` output and `pwdx` output side-by-side.