# g++ can't find txt files in the same directory (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, gcc, g++

In Xcode or Visual Studio, I was able to compile and run my codes successfully when I put my txt files within the same directory where the codes were located. These txt files had glsl codes in it for shading. However, now I want to run my files in the command line with g++. Just like in XCode, I put all my files(including the txt files) in the same directory, and ran the command

`g++ -o Animation glad.c Animation.cpp -lglfw.3`

The executable file 'Animation' is made in the same directory where all the other files were, but when I run it, I get the following error messages.

```
ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ
ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: PROGRAM
ERROR: Compiled vertex shader was corrupt.
ERROR: Compiled fragment shader was corrupt.
```

The render window does appear, but nothing is drawn since the program could not read my txt files.

Here are parts of the codes that can help you understand my problem. This is my Animation.cpp code

```
#include "Camera.h"
#include "Shader.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // uncomment this statement to fix compilation on OS X
#endif

    if(!glfwInit())
        return -1;
                                                         // glfw window creation
                                                         // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    // tell GLFW to capture our mouse
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //Where the error happens
    Shader shader("AnimationVertexShader.txt", "AnimationFragmentShader.txt");
    shader.use();
    ......
}
```

This is the Shader.h code

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Shader
{
public:
    unsigned int ID;
    // constructor generates the shader on the fly
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath, const char* geometryPath = nullptr)
    {
        // 1. retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::string geometryCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;
        std::ifstream gShaderFile;
        // ensure ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
        vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        gShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        try
        {
            // open files
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
            // read file's buffer contents into streams
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
            // close file handlers
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();
            // convert stream into string
            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
            // if geometry shader path is present, also load a geometry shader
            if (geometryPath != nullptr)
            {
                gShaderFile.open(geometryPath);
                std::stringstream gShaderStream;
                gShaderStream << gShaderFile.rdbuf();
                gShaderFile.close();
                geometryCode = gShaderStream.str();
            }
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
        }
        const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const char * fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
        // 2. compile shaders
        unsigned int vertex, fragment;
        int success;
        char infoLog[512];
        // vertex shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        checkCompileErrors(vertex, "VERTEX");
        // fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        checkCompileErrors(fragment, "FRAGMENT");
        // if geometry shader is given, compile geometry shader
        unsigned int geometry;
        if (geometryPath != nullptr)
        {
            const char * gShaderCode = geometryCode.c_str();
            geometry = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(geometry, 1, &gShaderCode, NULL);
            glCompileShader(geometry);
            checkCompileErrors(geometry, "GEOMETRY");
        }
        // shader Program
        ID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
        glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
        if (geometryPath != nullptr)
            glAttachShader(ID, geometry);
        glLinkProgram(ID);
        checkCompileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");
        // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);
        if (geometryPath != nullptr)
            glDeleteShader(geometry);

    }
    // activate the shader
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void use()
    {
        glUseProgram(ID);
    }
    // utility uniform functions
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setBool(const std::string &name, bool value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), (int)value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setInt(const std::string &name, int value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setFloat(const std::string &name, float value) const
    {
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec2(const std::string &name, const glm::vec2 &value) const
    {
        glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]);
    }
    void setVec2(const std::string &name, float x, float y) const
    {
        glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec3(const std::string &name, const glm::vec3 &value) const
    {
        glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]);
    }
    void setVec3(const std::string &name, float x, float y, float z) const
    {
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec4(const std::string &name, const glm::vec4 &value) const
    {
        glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]);
    }
    void setVec4(const std::string &name, float x, float y, float z, float w)
    {
        glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z, w);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat2(const std::string &name, const glm::mat2 &mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix2fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat3(const std::string &name, const glm::mat3 &mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat4(const std::string &name, const glm::mat4 &mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }

private:
    // utility function for checking shader compilation/linking errors.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void checkCompileErrors(GLuint shader, std::string type)
    {
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[1024];
        if (type != "PROGRAM")
        {
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

What would be the reason why g++ cannot read the txt files from the same directory? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No C++ systems that I am aware of look for data files in the same directory as the source files, except by accident. They look in the current working directory, which is the one you execute the executable from (which is not necessarily the one containing the executable).

Comment: @NeilButterworth Thank you for your comment! I'm confused though... Isn't the directory which holds the executable the current working directory?

Comment: No, it isn't. The CWD is the the directory you run the executable from. So, for example for  `./foo/bar/myprog.exe` the CWD is not `./foo/bar`, it is `.`

Comment: @NeilButterworth Hmm then is there a way that I can make the g++ search for data files in the same directory where the exe file and source files are?

Comment: one suggestion, for debugging purpose only and if you can not run your binary with debugger, whenever you open a file in UNIX just print file path. You will get your answers.

Comment: @Peter.. put your binary and TXT files in same directory. now run the binary and before reading files use `pwdx` with `pipe` to get binary path. use that path to open your TXT files. It`ll be done. This accepted answer is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671403/trying-to-join-output-from-ps-and-pwdx-linux-commands

Comment: The C++ compiler has nothing to do with how you load some data files atr runtime.

Comment: @Peter The directory the source files are in is a red herring, as when you distribute your program there probably won't be any. How you get the directory of the executable is OS-specific, but yes, you can do that - for example on Windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647429/c-windows-path-to-the-folder-where-the-executable-is-located

Comment: @someone How does this help the OP get the directory containing the _executable_?

Comment: @PaulSanders... I suggested him to provide full path of that file which he want to read from binary. Once he got executable path he can build path for TXT files to be read at run time. Please read my previous comments.

Comment: @someone But `pwdx` provides the current working directory, and not (necessarily) the directory containing the executable.

Comment: @PaulSanders... According to man pages https://linux.die.net/man/1/pwdx. Well if not necessarily then we need to find a way with 100% probability. I was just suggesting how simply he can debug the issue.